# Push to HG repository through http

Tags: apache, mercurial, push

I've just made a hg server with apache. I'm able to clone, pull but not to push to some older repositories.

If I made a clean repository on the server, clone it, made and commit a test file, push works fine.

If I use an existing repository made from svn, the push doesn't work. This repository was hosted on an older hg server which we shared with an other project. There it worked fine. But after migrating  to newer hg, this started to happen:

```
$ hg push -r 2 --debug --traceback http://sdsvn.mbid.cz:3145/b
pushing to http://sdsvn.mbid.cz:3145/b
using http://sdsvn.mbid.cz:3145/b
proxying through http://wsab1.lb.mbid.cz:8008
sending capabilities command
http authorization required for http://sdsvn.mbid.cz:3145/b
realm: Moneta Apps Mercurial repository
user: macik
password:
http auth: user macik, password *******
query 1; heads
sending batch command
searching for changes
all remote heads known locally
preparing listkeys for "phases"
sending listkeys command
received listkey for "phases": 15 bytes
checking for updated bookmarks
preparing listkeys for "bookmarks"
sending listkeys command
received listkey for "bookmarks": 0 bytes
sending branchmap command
sending branchmap command
preparing listkeys for "bookmarks"
sending listkeys command
received listkey for "bookmarks": 0 bytes
1 changesets found
list of changesets:
6b69f3649ab68022671048cdd56e94bdfa3d2f8c
bundle2-output-bundle: "HG20", 4 parts total
bundle2-output-part: "replycaps" 155 bytes payload
bundle2-output-part: "check:heads" streamed payload
bundle2-output-part: "changegroup" (params: 1 mandatory) streamed payload
bundle2-output-part: "pushkey" (params: 4 mandatory) empty payload
sending unbundle command
sending 13699 bytes
bundle2-input-bundle: with-transaction
bundle2-input-part: "output" (advisory) (params: 0 advisory) supported
bundle2-input-part: total payload size 18
remote: adding changesets
bundle2-input-part: "output" (advisory) supported
bundle2-input-part: total payload size 38
remote: transaction abort!
remote: rollback completed
bundle2-input-part: "error:abort" (params: 1 mandatory) supported
bundle2-input-bundle: 2 parts total
remote: stream ended unexpectedly (got 0 bytes, expected 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 239, in _runcatchfunc
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 842, in _dispatch
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 594, in runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 850, in _runcommand
  File "mercurial\dispatch.pyo", line 839, in <lambda>
  File "mercurial\util.pyo", line 1051, in check
  File "mercurial\commands.pyo", line 5292, in push
  File "mercurial\exchange.pyo", line 481, in push
  File "mercurial\exchange.pyo", line 922, in _pushbundle2
Abort: push failed on remote
abort: push failed on remote
```

I'm using mercurial 4.1 with Py2.7 and Apache2.2.31 on the server an TortoiseHG 4.1 on the client.

Unfortunately, I cann't install something as WireShark to monitor the trafic (corporate policies). So this is the only reasonable output I've.

Can you please direct me, where to look for root of this problem and even better how to solve it?

thx